# Hadoop - How to get a Path object of an HDFS file

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm trying to figure out the various ways to write content/files to the HDFS in a Hadoop cluster.

I know there is `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get()` and `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getLocal()` to create an output stream and write byte by byte.  If you are making use of `OutputCollector.collect()` it doesn't seem like this is the intended way to write to the HDFS.  I believe you have to use `Outputcollector.collect()` when implementing Mappers and Reducers, correct me if I'm wrong?.

I know you can set `FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath()` before even running the job but it looks like this can only accepts objects of type Path.

When looking at [org.apache.hadoop.fs.path](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.23.6/api/) and looking at the path class, I do not see anything which allows you to specify remote or local.  Then when looking up [org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.23.6/api/) I do not see anything which returns an object of type path.

1. Does `FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath()` always have to write to the local file system?  I don't think this is true, I vaguely remember reading that a jobs' output can be used as another jobs' input.  This leads me to believe there is also a way to set this to the HDFS.
2. Is the only way to write to the HDFS to use a data stream as described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get` and `org.apache.hadoop.FileSystem.getLocal` return a `FileSystem` object which is a generic that can be implemented both as a local filesystem or distibuted file system.
 `OutputCollector` doest write to hdfs . it just provides a method `collect` for mappers and reducers to collect the data output (both intermediate and final). By the way, its deprecated in favor of Context object.
`FileOutputFormat.setOuptPath` sets the final output directory  by setting `mapred.output.dir` which can be on your local file system or distributed. 
About remote or local - `fs.default.name` sets those value . If you have set it as `file:///` it will take local file system. if set as `hdfs://` it will take hdfs and so on. 
And about writing to hdfs - whatever method you take that writes to files in hadoop , it will be using `FSDataOuputStream` underneath. `FSDataOutputStrem` is wrapper of `java.io.OutputStream` . By the way, whenever you want to write to a filesystem in java, you have create a stream object for that.
FileOutputFormat has method `FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, output_path)` where in place of output_path , you can specify , whether you want to use local file system or hdfs , overriding the settings of core-site.xml. e.g `FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("hdfs://localhost:9000/path_to_file"))` will set up output to be written to hdfs. change it to file:/// and you can write to local file system. Change loclahost and portno as per your settings. In the same way, input can also be overridden at per job level. –

Comment: I'm giving it a shot now during my lunch/when I get home.  This seems to explain everything I needed.  If/when it works I'll accept the answer.  Thank you for your help Chandra.

Comment: I just checked my `conf/core-site.xml` file and I already have `hdfs://` set.  My output is going to my local file system though.  How do I specify an HDFS path when using `FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath()`  It has to accept something like `new Path(fileVar);` but that seems to return a local path and not an HDFS path regardless of what I have in my `conf/core-site.xml` file.

Comment: ok.. so your settings from core-site.xml are not imported. Use conf.addResource("path_to_core-site.xml"). And now try. btw, are you using some IDE or using jar? in case of jar , you shouldn't need this explicit setting.

Comment: I use an IDE to write the code but run via CML with a jar file.

Comment: But there is not a method to specify to use the HDFS or the local system for output?  It is just based on the `conf/core-site.xml` and cannot be achieved in the code?

Comment: FileOutputFormat has method FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, output_path) where in place of output_path , you can specify , whther you want to use local file system or hdfs , overriding the settings of  core-site.xml. e.g FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("hdfs://localhost:9000/path_to_file")) will set up output to be written to hdfs. change it to file:/// and you can write to local file system. Change loclahost and portno as per your settings.  In the same way, input can also be overridden at per job level.

Comment: Thank you, now I get it.  I was passing in arguments such as `/usr/dan` and did not realize I could use a URL rather than a system path. Can you just post as an answer so I can check it off?